# Email regex failing on certain email addresses

Tags: php, regex, email

I'm using this code to parse out emails from a string:

```
function get_emails ($str) {
    $pattern = '/([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])' .
    '(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)/i';

    preg_match ($pattern, $str, $matches);

    return $matches;
}
```

It works well except when the address has more than one period in domain.  So johndoe@yahoo.com works fine but johndoe@yahoo.co.uk get's cut at johndoe@yahoo.co

What can I change to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: If your email regex is less than a few thousand characters long, it's incorrect.

Comment: I found this on Stack Overflow somewhere.  It works with multiple periods: `([A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})`

Comment: your also assuming names and domains are English! a-z  Poor old Renée will be upset http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `+` before the end, i.e. `+/i`.